# React context not updated in props.children

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a requirement where I need to show a date range picker and the selected date range should be made available to all the components. I'm trying to use `React Context API` to get this to work.

Using `React.useContext()` I am able to see the updated value in all components except whatever is rendered in `{props.children}`

Below is the approach I've tried out.

Context.tsx

```
export const DateRangeContext = React.createContext<DateRangeContextType>({
    dateRange: {
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: new Date(),
    },
    setDateRange: (dateRange: DateRange) => {}
});
```

DateRangePicker.tsx

```
...
const { dateRange, setDateRange } = React.useContext(DateRangeContext);
...
const applyDateRange = (newDateRange: DateRange) => {
        const newDateRange = {
            startDate: newDateRange.startDate,
            endDate: newDateRange.endDate,
        };
        setDateRange(newDateRange);
};
```

PageLayout.tsx

```
...
<DateRangeContext.Provider value={{dateRange, setDateRange}}>
    <Header/>
    {props.children}
    <Footer/>
</DateRangeContext.Provider>
```

Dashboard.tsx

```
...
const { dateRange, setDateRange } = React.useContext(DateRangeContext);
...
<PageLayout>
   <Card>Card content goes here</Card>
</PageLayout>
...
```

In `PageLayout.tsx`, if I directly use `<Dashboard/>` in place of `{props.children}` I see the updated context value in Dashboard.tsx.

But when Dashboard component is passed to `{props.children}`, the context value doesn't get updated and I always see the initialized value.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but it worked after moving the provider to the `PageLayout` component's parent.

MainLayout.tsx

```
...
const [dateRange, setDateRange] = React.useState<DateRange>();
...
<DateRangeContext.Provider value={{dateRange, setDateRange}}>
  <PageLayout/>
</DateRangeContext.Provider>
```